# Get string from RecyclerView adapter in a fragment, then show it in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

The thing is, I want to get a String when I click an item from the first Fragment and then show it in the second Fragment (something like "setText(StringFromFirstFragment") but I can't figure out how to do it.
I've been searching and some people say that an interface would made the job, but I don't know how to create it and retrieve the info in the second Fragment:

First one is "Home" fragment and has a Recyclerview

[image: Home fragment]

Then I have the second fragment that appears when you click on an item from the RecyclerView

[image]

Here is my Adapter code:

```
public class myadapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter2.myviewholder2> {



List<String> items;

ArrayList<datamodel2> dataholder2;
Context mContext;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private String uid;
private DatabaseReference myRef;



public myadapter2(ArrayList<datamodel2> dataholder2) {
    this.dataholder2 = dataholder2;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
    mContext = parent.getContext();


    return new myadapter2.myviewholder2(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder2 holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(dataholder2.get(position).getImageurl()).into(holder.CircleImg);
    holder.header.setText(dataholder2.get(position).getHeader());
    holder.descr.setText(dataholder2.get(position).getDescr());
    holder.price.setText(dataholder2.get(position).getPrec());
    holder.usuarioVenta.setText(dataholder2.get(position).getUsuario());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio2);
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "clicked : name "+textView.getText().toString());
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.articuloVenta);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataholder2.size();
}

class myviewholder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CircleImageView CircleImg;
    TextView header, descr, price, usuarioVenta;

    public myviewholder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CircleImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circle2);
        header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtheader2);
        descr = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescr2);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio2);
        usuarioVenta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtusuario2);


    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position, Object object);
}
```

}

And here is my second fragment code:

```
public class articuloVenta extends Fragment  {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public articuloVenta() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment articuloVenta.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static articuloVenta newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    articuloVenta fragment = new articuloVenta();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        String strtext = getArguments().getString("name");
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulo_venta, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button mbtnArticuloVenta = view.findViewById(R.id.btnVerInformación);
    EditText mtxtNombreArt = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreArtVenta);
    EditText mtxtPrecio = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecioVenta);
    TextView descripcion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLabelDesc2);
    descripcion.setText("Aquí se mostrará la descripción del artículo seleccionado");
    mtxtNombreArt.setFocusable(false);
    mtxtPrecio.setFocusable(false);


    mbtnArticuloVenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.perfilVendedor);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my navigation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/inicio">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inicio"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.Inicio"
        android:label="@string/menu_inicio"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_inicio" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_inicio_to_articuloVenta"
            app:destination="@id/articuloVenta" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/perfil"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.Perfil"
        android:label="@string/menu_perfil"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_perfil" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/articulos"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.articulos"
        android:label="@string/menu_articulos"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_articulos" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_articulos_to_agregarart"
            app:destination="@id/agregarart" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/agregarart"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.agregarart"
        android:label="@string/menu_agregararticulos"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_agregarart" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_agregarart_to_articulos"
            app:destination="@id/articulos" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/articuloVenta"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.articuloVenta"
        android:label="@string/articulo_seleccionado"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_articulo_venta" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_articuloVenta_to_inicio"
            app:destination="@id/inicio" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_articuloVenta_to_perfilVendedor"
            app:destination="@id/perfilVendedor" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/perfilVendedor"
        android:name="com.example.marketplaceproject.perfilVendedor"
        android:label="@string/vendedor"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_perfil_vendedor" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_perfilVendedor_to_articuloVenta"
            app:destination="@id/articuloVenta" />
    </fragment>


</navigation>
```

Comment: share your navigation xml

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass arguments between destinations by using Bundle objects. Create a Bundle object and pass it to the destination using navigate(), as shown below:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio2);
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putString("text", textView.getText().toString());
            
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "clicked : name "+textView.getText().toString());
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.articuloVenta,bundle);
        }
    });
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked, I didn't know you can use navigate() to pass Bundle objects... THANKS AGAIN!!!